Prometheus dashboard not displaying
I have an application deployed on aks cluster exposed using ingress nginx.
I can access that application fine.
Then I setup prometheus on the kubernetes cluster using commands:
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus --namespace prometheus

Then I created an ingress manifest as:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-prometheus-ic
  namespace: prometheus
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /graph
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
                port:
                  number: 9090

But when I try to access the application on chrome, the page displays blank:

Since the page title shows: "Prometheus Time Series Collection and Processing Server", that means its routing fine.
I have enabled javascript on chrome, so that's not the reason for empty page. I have debugged the pods, services etcetera but dont find anything missing.
Any idea what I could be missing?
After further analysis, what I find is that this seems like a misconfigured ingress settings. The page looks ok, if I match the page title it is same as what normal prometheus ui is. It just seems it is unable to load static content from prometheus, js and css files. Look at the debugger from chrome:


You can use the inbuilt prometheus and grafana monitoring under AKS monitoring tab right?

As I mentioned in comments you can use the in-built Prometheus and Grafana dashboard under the monitoring insight tab of your aks cluster on the left-hand side panel. You can check out the setup from their MS Doc

However, if you want to go via the helm route then you can follow the below steps-
Add and update the chart.
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update

Create a dedicated namespace for your ease
kubectl create namespace prometheus

Install prometheus
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus --namespace prometheus

Once installed, verify if pods are up
kubectl get pods -n prometheus


Create an Ingress Resource for Prometheus, update the route with proper host
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-prometheus-ic
  namespace: prometheus
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /graph
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: prometheus-server
                port:
                  number: 80

apply it
 kubectl apply -f prometheus-ingress.yaml
 


I am using local host here for the sake of example but if you have your domain then modify the ingress accordingly to
spec:
  rules:
    - host: prometheus.yourdomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /graph
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: prometheus-server
                port:
                  number: 9090

Ensure the Prometheus service is configured to expose port (your port) in my case it is 9090
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server
  namespace: prometheus
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus

Done. Now do a port forward (the port you used)
kubectl port-forward -n prometheus svc/prometheus-server 9090:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9090 -> 9090


Reference:
Monitor AKS with prometheus and grafana

I was able to solve this issue. I didnt understand how the ingress's path based routing worked.
I added a random path "/graph" to the prometheus's ingress. Whereas the prometheus service was available at default path  ( which is '/')
Plus my other deployed app on the cluster available on different port than prometheus but was also served on default path
as a result I was not able to access the prometheus ui... we cant route to a random path in ingress. it has to match the path where app  is available.
to serve 2 applications at default path, we need to add different hostnames to them
